# Why CLion (cmake) doesn't require include <string> to build when VS does?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, clion

Why the following code build without issue using CLion but fails using Visual Studio?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    cout << "Enter your name:" << endl;
    cin >> str;

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

To make it work with Visual Studio, I must add

```
#include <string>
```

Both are building with an obsolete version of C++ (2003) which is a requirement.
Here's my CMakeLists.txt for CLion

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(foo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--std=c++03")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(foo ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Is it a configuration in CLion? Is it in CMake?

Comment: There is no requirement in the standard that <iostream> can't include <string>

Comment: ***Is it a configuration in CLion? Is it in CMake?*** Neither. Its the differences between compilers.

Comment: Standard headers are allowed, but not required, to include other standard headers. Different implementations have different chains of includes. Relying on a particular dependency makes your code non-portable: aways include the appropriate standard header for every element of standard library that you use.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, is there a way to force it? Aka make the build fail if those includes are missing?

Comment: Not to my knowledge; I wish there were. Basically, to increase the chance your code is portable, compile it on many different compilers (as many as you care to put the effort into).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a configuration in CLion? Is it in CMake? Neither. Its the differences between compilers.
>
> - drescherjm

> Standard headers are allowed, but not required, to include other standard headers. Different implementations have different chains of includes. Relying on a particular dependency makes your code non-portable: aways include the appropriate standard header for every element of standard library that you use.
>
> - Igor Tandetnik

> is there a way to force it? Aka make the build fail if those includes are missing?

You could try looking into using [Include What You Use](https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use), but I'm not sure if it can check for this. Quoting from the readme:

> "Include what you use" means this: for every symbol (type, function, variable, or macro) that you use in foo.cc (or foo.cpp), either foo.cc or foo.h should include a .h file that exports the declaration of that symbol. (Similarly, for foo_test.cc, either foo_test.cc or foo.h should do the including.) Obviously symbols defined in foo.cc itself are excluded from this requirement.